# I want Bold text for my java coded Telegram bot, how?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send bold text via a bot.
To send it as a normal person you would have to type 2 stars in front and behind the message, but this doesn't work for the bot. I have searched for a solution here but most bots are developed in PHP or Python.

```
   `String a = emoji+"**dump alert**\n";
    String b = "Date and time: ";
    String c = month+" "+date.format(format1)+" / "+date.format(format2)+"\n";
    String d = "Exchange: "+exc;
    return a+b+c+d;`
```

Answer (score 3):

For work with html tags in **Text** you need ON this options.
You can do it edit this flag:

```
message.enableHtml(true);
```

After this you can set bold text use this example:

```
String text = "<b>Bold text</b>";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you work with Markdown you should use only one star `*bold*`

Comment: ah, found it. sorry i am a rooki and i didn't even knew what markdown was.

Comment: @S.Scholte When the answer work for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with html tags. So instead of

```
String a = emoji+"**dump alert**\n";
```

try using this

```
String a = emoji+"<b>dump alert</b>\n";
```

Comment: i tried but it just prints our the <b>signs too. Sorry, i wasn't clear enough. it is my first question. here is another part of my code. 'SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage().setChatId("@intelligentPumps"); sendMessage.setText(alert(month[monthInt - 1], parts[6], date));' the alert is me method returning these strings.